# Historia de un maromo

Tags: etimología, historia, españa, sustantivos

La voz *[maromo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OStsnQr)* la aprendí en Málaga, donde era sinónimo de "noviete". En España se usa dicha palabra como:

> 1. m. coloq. Novio o amante masculino. *Se ha echado un maromo.*
> 2. m. coloq. Individuo, tío, fulano.

Este fin de semana me contaron una historia sobre su origen, el cual según la RAE proviene de *[maroma](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OSrdjLb)* ("cuerda gruesa"). La historia decía que antiguamente en las playas se ponían unas maromas en el agua para evitar que la gente, que no sabía nadar como ahora, se ahogara. En un extremo de la maroma había un señor, generalmente fornido, que se encargaba de manejar la maroma y arrastrar a la gente hasta la orilla en caso necesario. A este señor se le comenzó a denominar "el maromo". De ahí pasaría a los otros significados: si tu novio era un tío apuesto y musculado era "un buen maromo".

Buscando contrastar este origen leo en *Etimologías de Chile* [una historia similar](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?maroma), pero ambientada en Madrid: se llamaba así a los mozos de cuerda que frecuentaban las plazas esperando ser contratados para cargar fardos y demás. Lo que me ha sorprendido es que su uso también derivó en otro que no me esperaba: para denominar a los chulos de las prostitutas; y en ese caso se puede usar en frases como "ya está fulanita con su maromo" como indicando que el novio no la deja ni a sol ni a sombra, como si fuera su posesión.

La acepción de *maromo* como "mozo de cuerda" la encuentro en un [texto de 1930](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0004889785&page=17&search=maromo&lang=es), en una historia acerca de un chico que tenía que recoger un haz de leña y llevarlo hasta casa, y tras una charla con el diablo acaba diciendo que "hoy no estoy dispuesto a hacer el maromo".

Cuestiones que quedarían para completar la historia de la voz *maromo*:

- ¿Cuán antigua es la palabra? La web de etimologías menciona el siglo XIX, ¿qué ejemplos hay de su uso anteriores a 1930?
- ¿Tiene la palabra una connotación negativa o incluso peyorativa en algún lugar? La web cita el uso de *maromo* como "chulo de prostituta" en Madrid, ¿se ha mantenido ese uso o fue algo pasajero?

Comment: La historia de las maromas en el agua me ayuda a entender el origen de las *marometas* (somersaults).